# How to re-ID multidimensional arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array in php. I have also a DB, which has the same data, but different ID for them. I have to match the two ...

```
$ad_types = array(
    array('Személyi kölcsön', 0, array(
        'Adósságrendező hitel',
        'Hitel autóvásárlásra',
        'Szabad felhasználású hitel',
        'Hitelkiváltás',
        'Hitel fix részletre',
        'Online hitel',
        'Akciós hitel',
        'Gyorskölcsön',
        'Hitel alacsony kamatra',
        'Kis összegű hitel',
    )),
    array('Jelzáloghitel', 0, array(
        'Jelzáloghitel használt lakásra',
        'CSOK',
        'Akciós jelzáloghitelek',
        'Adósságrendező hitel',
        'Szabad felhasználású hitel',
        'Jelzáloghitel építésre/bővítésre',
        'Jelzáloghitel korszerűsítésre',
        'Jelzáloghitel fix részletre',
        'Jelzáloghitel alacsony kamatra'
    )),
    array('Hitelkártya', 5, array(
        'Pontgyűjtő',
        'Akciós',
        'Aranykártya',
        'Kedvező tankolás'
    )),
);
```

I have to re-ID them, so their ID would look like:

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id | name                                    |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|  0 | Személyi kölcsön                        |
|  1 | Adósságrendező hitel                    |
|  2 | Hitel autóvásárlásra                    |
|  3 | Szabad felhasználású hitel              |
|  4 | Hitelkiváltás                           |
|  5 | Hitel fix részletre                     |
|  6 | Online hitel                            |
|  7 | Akciós hitel                            |
|  8 | Gyorskölcsön                            |
|  9 | Hitel alacsony kamatra                  |
| 10 | Kis összegű hitel                       |
| 11 | Jelzáloghitel                           |
| 12 | Jelzáloghitel használt lakásra          |
| 13 | CSOK                                    |
| 14 | Akciós jelzáloghitelek                  |
| 15 | Adósságrendező hitel                    |
| 16 | Szabad felhasználású hitel              |
| 17 | Jelzáloghitel építésre/bővítésre        |
| 18 | Jelzáloghitel korszerűsítésre           |
| 19 | Jelzáloghitel fix részletre             |
| 20 | Jelzáloghitel alacsony kamatra          |
| 21 | Hitelkártya                             |
| 22 | Pontgyűjtő                              |
| 23 | Akciós                                  |
| 24 | Aranykártya                             |
| 25 | Kedvező tankolás                        |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
```

how can i do that, do their ID will match with the one in my DB?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried that is not working as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function reIdArray($array)
{
    $reIdArray = array();
    foreach ($array as $subArray) {
        $reIdArray = array_merge($reIdArray, array($subArray[0]), $subArray[2]);
    }
    return $reIdArray;
}

// print_r(reIdArray($ad_types));
```